# Is there a shortcut to collapse all functions/methods in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm tired of collapsing all my long functions individually and was wondering if there's a shortcut on VS Code to collapse all folding text?

Answer (score 10):

You can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> one after the other.

Comment: and to unfold all, you can press Ctrl + K Ctrl + J

Comment: these don't work at all in my VS nor can I find anything in the drop downs.

Comment: @MikeB2019x can you tell what exactly you are trying?

Comment: I have a code in VS Code.  I can collapse and expand functions/methods manually using the `>`.  None of the the kybd shortcuts above do anything.  Using VS Code 1.75.0.  Have tried relevant commands in this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf.  Note that  for one file, trying the shortcuts appears to have removed the `>` functionality.

Comment: @MikeB2019x - Same here. I noticed fold all / unfold all shared the same keyboard shortcut `Cmd +K + 0`. I had to set one of them to `Cmd +K + )`

Comment: Note that is zero not the letter O

Answer (score 0):

For me, now, to collapse all functions is:

Ctrl + K Ctrl + 0

Look for updated full list in Visual Studio Code / Help / Keyboard Shortcuts Reference